# Asymptotic Curves on a 1-sheeted hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a 1-sheeted hyperboloid given in local coordinates by $X(u,v) = (u, v, \pm \sqrt{u^2 + v^2 - 1})$.  I have to find the asymptotic curves on this surface.

I have found the first fundamental form:
$E = 1 + \frac{u^2}{u^2 + v^2 -1}$,
$F = \frac{u v}{u^2 + v^2 -1}$,
$G = 1 + \frac{v^2}{u^2 + v^2 -1}$.

Therefore:
$\sqrt{E G - F^2} = \sqrt{2 + \frac{1}{u^2 + v^2 -1}}$.

So, the normal vector is:
$N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{E G - F^2}} ( \mp \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 -1}}, \mp \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^2 + v^2 -1}}, 1)$.

Thus, the second fundamental form is given by:
$e = \pm \frac{v^2 - 1}{(u^2 + v^2 -1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{E G - F^2}}$,
$f = \mp \frac{u v}{(u^2 + v^2 -1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{E G - F^2}}$,
$g = \pm \frac{u^2 - 1}{(u^2 + v^2 -1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{E G - F^2}}$.

The Gaussian curvature is:
$K = -\frac{1}{2 u^2 + 2 v^2 - 1)^2}$; (I think that the sign does not depend on the "$\pm$").

I have, of course, computed the first- and second-order derivatives of $X$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ each.

(Can you check me on my work thus far?)

From this information, how can I find the asymptotic directions on the surface?  I would prefer to avoid ugly differential equations.  Should/Could I express $dN$ in terms of matrices of the first and second fundamental forms (the first being inverted and then multiplying the second; by Weingarten) and work from that?  I would like as general of a method as possible, rich in explanation and detail, and then its application to this particular example being shown.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotic directions are given by the zero directions of

$$e~\mathrm{d}u^2+2f~\mathrm{d}u~\mathrm{d}v+g~\mathrm{d}v^2=0$$

Consider the case ${\bf X}(u,v) = \left(u,v,\sqrt{u^2+v^2-1}\right)$.

According to my calculations, assuming that $u^2 + v^2 \ge 1$, this is equivalent to
$$(v^2-1)~\mathrm{d}u^2 - 2uv~\mathrm{d}u~\mathrm{d}v+(u^2-1)~\mathrm{d}v^2=0$$

The zero directions of the quadratic differential form are:
$$( uv \pm \sqrt{u^2+v^2-1}:v^2-1)$$
Can you do the case${\bf X}(u,v) = \left(u,v,-\sqrt{u^2+v^2-1}\right)$?

Comment: What is a homogeneous coordinate?

Can you do it without differential equations?

Comment: @kevin There are no differential equations. I'm just solving a quadratic! This is *very bad notation*, but I want directions $(\mathrm{d}u:\mathrm{d}v)$ for which $e~\mathrm{d}u^2 + 2f~\mathrm{d}u~\mathrm{d}v+g~\mathrm{d}v^2=0$. For example, if I have $\mathrm{d}u^2 - \mathrm{d}v^2 =0$ then the directions would have $\mathrm{d}u^2 = \mathrm{d}v^2$ or $\mathrm{d}u = \pm \mathrm{d}v$. In other words $(1:1)$ and $(-1:1)$ would be the directions.

Comment: @kevin The notation $(x:y)$ means all things like $(x,y)$, $(2x,2y)$, $(3x,3y)$, $(-4x,-4y)$, etc. It gives a direction instead of a vector. So $(x:y)$ are all vectors parallel to $(x,y)$.

Comment: @kevin P.S. Don't forget to up-vote answers that you find helpful and to select your favorite answer. This website's currency is "reputation" which comes from people voting on answers and questions that they find interesting and/or useful.

Comment: Since each $e$, $f$, $g$ are determined by the "$\pm$" sign, switching the signum only there would result in multiplying the first equation in your answer by (-1) on the lefthand side (only).  Since it is equal to 0, dividing by (-1) on both sides produces the exact equation that you gave, which will produce the same results.